# Creating list in Vue.js with Vuetify --> Error: avoid using JavaScript keyword as "v-on"

Tags: list, vue.js, vuetify.js

Just want to create a simple list in Vue.js with Vuetify. I got an error like: Avoid using JavaScript keyword as "v-on" value: ""  vue/valid-v-on. Please be specific in your possible answer, since I'm a beginner with Vuetify and Vue.js.

This is my template code:

```
<template>
    <v-container grid-list-md >
      <v-card-title class="pa-0 pb-2">Tracks</v-card-title>

      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, index) in items"
                :key="index"
                @click=""
        >
          <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-icon
                    class="grey lighten-1 white--text"
                    v-text="'folder'"
            ></v-icon>
          </v-list-item-avatar>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.artist"></v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>

          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">mdi-information</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-list-item-action>
        </v-list-item>

      </v-list>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

And this is my script code:

```
  export default {
    name: "Home",
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        { name: 'Test1', artist: 'Artist1' },
        { name: 'Test2', artist: 'Artist2' },
        { name: 'Test3', artist: 'Artist3' },
      ]
    }),
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure @click has a method inside it
don't just put **@click=""**

well put **@click="test"** , where test is an explicit method in the **methods** object